# How to use Egit with BitBucket to sync a project across two computers, this project needs to use ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

I've read and read and I'm still confused on the concept as described in the title: how do I maintain sync'd code between two computers, using Egit w/ BitBucket, when an Android library project like ActionBarSherlock is required?

I guess things got complicated for me when I started thinking about Eclipse workspaces vs. local git files. I am now very confused on the most efficient way to be syncing between two computers. I am able to do it now, but it's very cumbersome and ALWAYS the project-properties is incorrect about the path to the ActionBarSherlock library.

**TL;DR - This being said, what is the high level concept for easily pushing and pulling code from BitBucket without dependencies getting broken in the process?**

Also, should I have a full copy of my project in my workspace AND in the local git directories? I believe I should as one mirrors the other? Or should I only have 1 physical set of files, in the local git directories, which is logically referenced to from Eclipse (as opposed to having the physical files copied to the workspace itself).

Thank you for clearing this up,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: Here's what you do. Set up the development environment to use the same workspace path on both development machines. I switched mine to 'C:\Development\Android\workspace'.

Next, I imported ActionBarSherlock into the workspace I just created (make sure you copy the files into the workspace), do this on both development computers.

Now, ensure the path to the local Git files is the same on both machines, it needs to be the same as the path to your library project will be relative, and not fixed (../../ instead of C:/...). In this case, I'm using 'C:/Development/Git' for the local Git directory.

Next, import the Git project by cloning it from URI using the BitBucket URL for the project you set up. Right click on the project you just cloned, select Properties > Android, at the bottom of the Android tab, add ActionBarSherlock as a new library.

Commit and push the changes to the project.properties file. Voila! If both computers use the same paths, your library project will work as it should when updating your Gits!